# Convert Java interface to JSON String using GSON without encapsulating serialization in a JSON object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

### Background

I want to serialize an interface into a JSON object. For instance, say I have the following interface:

```
public interface Person {
    String getName();
    int getAge();
}
```

Which is implemented by the class `PersonImpl`:

```
public class PersonImpl implements Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public PersonImpl(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

`PersonSerializer.java` is used to serialize the interface using GSON:

```
public class PersonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Person> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Person src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject person = new JsonObject();
        person.addProperty("name", src.getName());
        person.addProperty("age", src.getAge());
        return person; // Breakpoint BP1
    }
}
```

I then use a `GsonBuilder` to serialize the interface:

```
Person person = new PersonImpl("Bob", 42);
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Person.class, new PersonSerializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
String personAsJsonString = gson.toJson(person); // Breakpoint BP2
```

### Issue

The problem is the `Person` class is being serialized as follows:

```
// Not what I want
{
    "person": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 42
    }
}
```

However, I only want the data within `person`:

```
// What I want
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 42
}
```

### Troubleshooting & Debugging

At Breakpoint BP1 (noted via the comment), the String value of `person` is exactly what I want. However, by Breakpoint BP2, after GSON completes serialization of the interface (i.e. `personAsJsonString`), it is the undesired result.

How can I get GSON to serialize a custom interface without encapsulating the result in a JSON Object?

### Edit (root cause found)

I completely failed to mention that I was using the Decorator Pattern, which happened to be the root cause of the issue.

```
public abstract class PersonDecorator implements Person {
    protected Person person;

    public PersonDecorator(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return person.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return person.getAge();
    }
}
```

Below is an example Decorator:

```
public class MrPersonDecorator extends PersonDecorator {
    public MrPersonDecorator(Person person) {
        super(person);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Mr. " + person.getName();
    }
}
```

So the issue happened when creating a `Person` instance via a decorator:

```
Person person = new MrPersonDecorator(new PersonImpl("Bob", 42));
```

In this case, I was not getting a reference to the interface itself, but rather the decorator, which also contains an instance of the interface along with implementing it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Which version of gson do you use?

Comment: @qwwdfsad 2.3.1. Which version did you use?

Comment: Exactly case from you question is serialized without rootname (as it should be). Either specify your question or check your code please

Comment: @qwwdfsad Which version of GSON did you try?

Comment: @qwwdfsad I found the root cause and updated the question. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson doesn't provide such mechanics (note, that it's not a principal constraint, e.g. Jackson provides it via `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation or `SerializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` on mapper).

What you can do is to either provide custom serializer for adapter like this:

```
public class PersonDecoratorSerializer implements JsonSerializer<PersonDecorator> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(PersonDecorator src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return context.serialize(src.getOriginalPerson()); 
    }
}
```

To avoid violating encapsulation you can add package-private `getOriginalPerson()` method to `PersonDecorator` and create serializer as inner static class so it can access this method.

Or wrap GSON calls to extract your person value: replace `gson.toJson(person)` with `gson.toJsonTree(person).getAsJsonObject().get("person").toString()`:

```
public static String toJson(Person person, Gson gson) {
    JsonObject object = gson.toJsonTree(person).getAsJsonObject();
    // Checks whether Person was PersonDecorator or not
    if (object.has("person")) {
      return object.get("person").toString();
    } else {
      return object.toString();
    }
}
```